# df.csv is not saving actual dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code works fine and prints all the desired values but when I try to save as df to csv all the rows are the same.

a.csv file content

Domains

A.com

AMD.com

AMD.com

AOL.com

AOL.com

AWS.com

AWS.com

3ammagazine.com

3dmail.com

3email.com

3xl.net

444.net

4email.com

4email.net

4mg.com

4newyork.com

whdskcisail.com

wrestlingpages.com

wrexham.net

```
import whois
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
import socket
import os
import csv 
import datetime
import time
import requests
from ipwhois import IPWhois
from urllib import request
from ipwhois.utils import get_countries
import tldextract
from ipwhois.utils import get_countries
countries = get_countries(is_legacy_xml=True)
from ipwhois.experimental import bulk_lookup_rdap
from ipwhois.hr import (HR_ASN, HR_ASN_ORIGIN, HR_RDAP_COMMON, HR_RDAP, HR_WHOIS, HR_WHOIS_NIR)
countries = get_countries(is_legacy_xml=True)
import ipaddress

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', nrows=100)

#TimeOut Setting
s = socket.socket()
s.settimeout(10)

#Date Processing Function

def check_date_type(d):
    if type(d) is datetime.datetime:
        return d
    if type(d) is list:
        return d[0]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  try:
      DN = df.iloc[index]['Domains']
      ip = socket.gethostbyname(DN)
      ipwhois = IPWhois(ip).lookup_whois()
      print(DN)
      print(ip)
      print(ipwhois)
      df['IPcity'][index] = ipwhois['nets'][0]['city']
      df['ASNumber'][index] = ipwhois['asn']
      df['NetAddr'][index] = ipwhois['nets'][0]['address']
      df['NetCity'][index] = ipwhois['city']
      df['NetPostCode'][index] = ipwhois['nets'][0]['postal_code']
      df.to_csv('a1.csv', index=False)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e) 
    df['e'] = e # want to save the errors in a differet column
    df.to_csv('a2.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're overwriting the .csv file in every iteration of your loop. If you move the `df.to_csv()` outside of your loop, you will get your desired dataframe:

```
...
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  try:
      DN = df.iloc[index]['Domains']
      ip = socket.gethostbyname(DN)
      ipwhois = IPWhois(ip).lookup_whois()
      print(DN)
      print(ip)
      print(ipwhois)
      df['IPcity'][index] = ipwhois['nets'][0]['city']
      df['ASNumber'][index] = ipwhois['asn']
      df['NetAddr'][index] = ipwhois['nets'][0]['address']
      df['NetCity'][index] = ipwhois['city']
      df['NetPostCode'][index] = ipwhois['nets'][0]['postal_code']

  except Exception as e:
    print(e) 
    df['e'] = e # want to save the errors in a differet column
df.to_csv('a1.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Sorry but it is still not working (colab and pycharm). Have you run the code?